# How specify mimeType for read nfc tag with url

Tags: android, mime-types, nfc

I have a Uri NFC TAG with: `pay://myName/12345`

and in my intent filter i have:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

how do i specify the data of MIME-Type for launch my App without App chooser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, ideally, you would not invent a non-standard scheme like that. It is better to create a tag with an HTTP URL that points to a Web page, where you have an Android activity also handle that URL -- the Android activity's `<intent-filter>` will be more specific and therefore will take precedence when it is installed. That way, the tag works for many more devices.

That being said, regardless of the URL syntax, use an appropriate `<data>` element. Instead of using `android:mimeType`, use `android:scheme` and other attributes.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/NFC/URLTagger) that allows users to write a URL to an NDEF-compliant tag (shared via the Share options menu item in the browser). If you write a specific URL to the tag, the application also has an activity that will be launched when the tag is scanned, courtesy of this manifest entry:

```
    <activity android:name="URLHandler"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
          <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
          <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="commonsware.com"
                android:path="/nfctest"
          />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is exactly what i am searching and works :) thanks

Comment: Is this functionality is dropped?
Because on API level 30 there is always a picker with browser(s) and my application in the list.
And my intent filter looks exactly the same, except the actual URL.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal: I am uncertain what "this functionality" refers to. Web browsers are welcome to advertise support for NFC, and frankly I have not dealt with NFC in several years at this point.

Comment: @CommonsWare By functionality I mean -
launch the application which defines a certain URL with action `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`, else open the URL in browser.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal: Apparently, some browsers started supporting NFC directly, in the 11 years since I wrote this answer. Or perhaps Android treats `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED` as equivalent to `android.intent.action.VIEW` for `http`/`https` URLs or something nowadays. Again, I have not worked with NFC in a very long time.

Comment: @CommonsWare Probably, but I will continue my search anyways, let see what will be the results, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I got the solution, thought should share with you. Android supports (Android Application Records)[https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#aar] for API level 14 and above. Basically you can add AAR to a NFC card, and then that AAR combined with already defined intent-filter, opens your activity(application) or open play store to download it.